# category url rewrite doesn't work when magento running on nginx

Tags: url, nginx

I set up my magento store running on LEMP server. Every thing works fine except the url rewrite of category does not work.  If I use the url http://mystore.com/catalog/category/view/id/3, then I can see the category view page.  But if I click the category on the top menu and its url is rewritten to http://mystore.com/website-sale.html.  Then the category page is missing. I got the '404' error message.

Comment: "But if I click the category on the top menu and its url is rewritten to"  What's the pre-redirect URL?

Answer (score 2):

Magento explains [how to configure nginx](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/configuring_nginx_for_magento)

I thought about shortening the config, but I think this is a bad idea. I don't have any idea about nginx but afaik .htaccess doesn't work, so you have to configure rewrite to `index.php` by yourself.

But still have a look on the link for the global config!

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name DOMAIN.com;
rewrite / $scheme://www.$host$request_uri permanent; ## Forcibly prepend a www
}

server {
listen 80 default;
## SSL directives might go here
server_name www.DOMAIN.com *.DOMAIN.com; ## Domain is here twice so server_name_in_redirect will favour the www
root /var/www/vhosts/DOMAIN.com;

location / {
index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
try_files $uri $uri/ @handler; ## If missing pass the URI to Magento's front handler
expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
}

## These locations would be hidden by .htaccess normally
location ^~ /app/                { deny all; }
location ^~ /includes/           { deny all; }
location ^~ /lib/                { deny all; }
location ^~ /media/downloadable/ { deny all; }
location ^~ /pkginfo/            { deny all; }
location ^~ /report/config.xml   { deny all; }
location ^~ /var/                { deny all; }

location /var/export/ { ## Allow admins only to view export folder
auth_basic           "Restricted"; ## Message shown in login window
auth_basic_user_file htpasswd; ## See /etc/nginx/htpassword
autoindex            on;
}

location  /. { ## Disable .htaccess and other hidden files
return 404;
}

location @handler { ## Magento uses a common front handler
rewrite / /index.php;
}

location ~ .php/ { ## Forward paths like /js/index.php/x.js to relevant handler
rewrite ^(.*.php)/ $1 last;
}

location ~ .php$ { ## Execute PHP scripts
if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite / /index.php last; } ## Catch 404s that try_files miss

expires        off; ## Do not cache dynamic content
fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS $fastcgi_https;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_CODE default; ## Store code is defined in administration > Configuration > Manage Stores
fastcgi_param  MAGE_RUN_TYPE store;
include        fastcgi_params; ## See /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params
}
}
```

Comment: I use your config file in the sites-available folder, and run it. I still got the 404 error message. Rewrite to index.php does not work for this category rewrite issue. website-sale.html is defined in url field when you create the category from the backend.

Comment: Is there anyway to have LEMP server process the .htaccess file?  I know this problem is caused by not processing this .htaccess file in the root directory.

Comment: What do you mean by LEMP? LAMP? Linux Apache MySQL PHP? Then it should do by default. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12202387/htaccess-not-working-apache If you are running nginx take the config from above

Comment: I did take the config from above, but still got the same error.  What I mean is the nginx config above does not function the same as the .htaccess of LAMP.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know nginx ... I should have mentioned it. Only only know the ressources :-/

Comment: Do feel bad about it, I am the beginner of nginx too.

Answer (score 0):

Try system-->configuration and then in your Catalog menu, select catalog and set the "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" to no. This will remove category and catalog in your URLs without having to mess with rewrites.

Answer (score -1):

With nginx, Try this:

```
System > Configuration -> General > Web > Search Engines Optimization
Switch Use Web Server Rewrites to No
```